# Show Shopping Cart Total in Template

Tags: joomla, shopping-cart, virtuemart

Simple question but cannot find an answer in Google, I would like to show the Shopping Cart total in within the template of a Joomla website.

Do I have to query the database and calculate myself, or is there a function to perform this already?

Using Joomla 1.0.12 (yes I know, it's old)

Answer (score 0):

You could install the virtuemart cart module and publish that anywhere on your site.

Check the `Virtuemart_1.X.x_COMPLETE_PACKAGE_J_X.x_zip` in the `Modules` folder